# MacBook freezing?

Tags: mac, performance

While I was working with my (unibody, 10.5) MacBook, suddenly the display was covered by a grey shade and a message - in four languages - appeared, ordering me to restart the computer, and of course nothing else was working.
While I know that I should describe in detail all programs running etc., does anybody have an idea about what kind of problem could possibly have caused this? I don't believe it ever happened in almost three years with the same computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a Kernel Panic, and it probably wasn't your fault. They usually aren't a huge deal. 
[This Apple doc](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/8965.html) has information about what happened, and directions about what could have caused it and how to fix it.

In says about the problem:

> This message indicates that an error
>   occurred in the core of the operating
>   system, which is referred to as a
>   “kernel panic.”
>
> A kernel panic can be caused by
>   damaged or incompatible software or,
>   in rare cases, by damaged or
>   incompatible hardware. The most likely
>   cause of the problem is that a system
>   file or folder has been moved,
>   replaced, or damaged.

See the To Solve This Problem section for directions about recovery.

Comment: Great, this seems to be exactly what happened to me. I had deleted some "Application support" files for programs I had deleted. I hope I deleted one file too many. Thanks!